# Error:Error: Expected resource of type drawable [ResourceType]!

Tags: android

I've just tried to generate signed apk for one of my projects!

The project works good, but when I try to generate signed APK it shows me an error: `Error: Expected resource of type drawable [ResourceType]`

[image: image description]

Comment: use R.drawable.drawableName insted of te Integer.

Comment: Hello, could you clarify your answer pleaase, i'm not a developer so ...thanks for understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need pass `Drawable` in `setBackgroundDrawable()` method instead of  `int` value

Like below code

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_round));
```

Comment: Hello, could you clarify  your answer pleaase, i'm not a developer so ...thanks for understanding :)

Comment: @aker in **setBackgroundDrawable** method required parameter is **`drawable`**

Comment: @aker happy to help you